# how to remove an element from the end of the array and insert it to the front

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, data-structures

I am working with implement arraylist.  I want to write a method that takes the last element and inserts it at the front. So far I got it to take the last element and insert it in front, and shift everything over.  But, I can't seem to be able to delete the last element that was inserted in front.  for example: (1,2,5) to (5,1,2) but I got (5,1,2,5).  I am missing something in my replaceArray() method, but I don't really know what. Thanks for the help.

Constructor for the class:

```
public KWArrayList() {
    capacity = INITIAL_CAPACITY;
    theData = (E[]) new Object[capacity];
}

public void replaceArray(int index, E anElement) {
    for (int i = size; i > index; i--){
        theData[i] = theData[i - 1];
    }

    theData[index] = anEntry;

    size--;

    for (int i = 0; i < theData.length; i++){
        System.out.println(theData[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you required to use an arraylist?

Comment: If the method always puts the last element in the first position and shifts all the elements over to the right, why does it need any parameters? You can probably call it `rotate()` and have it copy the elements into a new array, it will copy the last element from the old array into the first position of the new array, and the rest of the elements in order.

Answer (score 1):

I would use this simple way of rotating the array (I think the method should be called `rotate` instead of `replaceAll`, because it's actually rotation the array by one position).

Here's the method `rotate()`:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void rotate() {
    Object[] temp = new Object[theData.length];
    //copy each element, except the first, from theData into temp by shifting one position off to the right
    for (int i = temp.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        temp[i] = theData[i - 1];
    }
    //move the last element into the first position
    temp[0] = theData[theData.length - 1];
    //update theData
    theData = (T[]) temp;
}
```

### Complete testable example

```
public class MyArrayList<T> {
    int INITIAL_CAPACITY = 10;
    int capacity;
    T[] theData;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public MyArrayList() {
        capacity = INITIAL_CAPACITY;
        theData = (T[]) new Object[capacity];
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public MyArrayList(int capacity) {
        this.capacity = capacity;
        theData = (T[]) new Object[this.capacity];
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void rotate() {
        Object[] temp = new Object[theData.length];
        //copy each element, except the first, from theData into temp by shifting one position off to the right
        // to the right
        for (int i = temp.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            temp[i] = theData[i - 1];
        }
        // move the last element into the first position
        temp[0] = theData[theData.length - 1];
        // update theData
        theData = (T[]) temp;
    }

    /**
     * For testing purposes only. It doesn't handle out of bounds values of
     * index.
     */
    private void insert(T t, int index) {
        theData[index] = t;
    }

    public void print() {
        for (T t : theData) {
            System.out.print(t + ", ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    @SafeVarargs
    public static <E> MyArrayList<E> of(E... elements) {
        MyArrayList<E> m = new MyArrayList<>(elements.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            m.insert(elements[i], i);
        }
        return m;
    }
}
```

Test the `rotate()` method:

```
public class TestMyArrayList {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyArrayList<Integer> m = MyArrayList.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
        m.print();
        m.rotate();
        m.print();
    }
}
```

It will print out:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
5, 1, 2, 3, 4,
```

Answer (score 0):

I've written this implementation. I'm assuming `theData` is of type `int` but you can change it to whatever. I also removed the parameters in the function since I don't use them.

1. First we copy the array into a `temp` variable.
2. Second, we save the first value in `theData` into another temp variable.
3. We then begin to shift starting from the beginning of `theData` until the second to last index.
4. Finally, we copy the first index saved from `theData` into `first` and assign it to the last index of the array.
5. Print

   ```
   public void replaceArray() {
        int [] temp = theData;
        int last = theData[theData.length - 1];
        for (int i = theData.length - 1; i > 0; i--){
            temp[i] = theData[i - 1];
        }

        temp[0] = last;

        for (int i = 0; i < theData.length; i++){
            System.out.println(temp[i]);
        }
   }
   ```

Comment: `theData` is an array, this statement `int temp = theData;` will result in a compile-time error.

Comment: @ahoxha Missed that. Thanks

Comment: You still got it wrong though. The question is not to put the first element in the end, but the other way around - the last element first and shift the rest of the elements to the right. Also, `temp[theData.length] = first;` will result in an `ArrayOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class KWArrayList <E>{
    private E[] data; /* your list */
    private int nbElt = 0; /* nb of element in your list */
    /* no need to store the capacity since data.length give it */
    KWArrayList(int capacity){
        data = (E[]) new Object[capacity]; /* create */
    }

    private void resize() {
        E[] tmp = (E[]) new Object[2 * data.length]; /* if the number of element >= capacity you double the capacity and copy old elt */
        data = Arrays.copyOf(data, 2 * data.length);
    }

    public void add(E elt) {
        if(nbElt >= data.length) {
            resize();
        }
        data[nbElt++] = elt; /* add an elt */
    }

    public void add(E ... elt) { /* add multiple elt */
        for(E e : elt) {
            add(e);
        }
    }

    public E removeLast() { /* remove the last elt and return it */
        if(nbElt == 0) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("nothing to remove");
        }
        return data[--nbElt];
    }

    public void removeLastAndInsertFront() {
        data[0] = removeLast();
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("[");
        if(nbElt == 0) {
            return sb.append("]").toString();
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < nbElt; i++) {
            sb.append(data[i]).append(", ");
        }
        sb.setLength(sb.length() - 2);
        return sb.append("]").toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        KWArrayList<Integer> data = new KWArrayList(1);
        data.add(1, 2, 5);
        System.out.println(data);
        System.out.println("first delete");
        data.removeLastAndInsertFront();
        System.out.println(data);
        System.out.println("second delete");
        data.removeLastAndInsertFront();
        System.out.println(data);
        System.out.println("third delete");
        data.removeLastAndInsertFront();
        System.out.println(data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyArrayList extends ArrayList<Object>{

    public void rotateRight(){
        this.add(0, this.remove(this.size()-1));
    }
    public void rotateLeft(){
        this.add(this.remove(0));
    }

}
```

Answer (score -3):

- use queue
- if you waht your own, have a 2 ints of the positions of the begin and end of the list, while replaceArray just copy the element to position end; then end =  (end+1) % capacity;begin = (begin +1) % capacity; (without removing - no need)